# How to use some operator that has been scraped from a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I'm trying to add, subtract or multiply two integers based on the sign between the integers, as in `5 + 6`. When I use ***+*** explicitly within the script, it works. However, I wish to parse that operator from the given string in order to use like `int(numbers[0]) + operator + int(numbers[1])` or something similar that works.

I've tried with:

```
import re

str_number = "5 + 6"

numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', str_number)
operator = re.findall('([^\s\d]+?)',str_number)[0]
result = int(numbers[0]) + operator + int(numbers[1])
print(result)
```

When I run the above, I get the error below:

```
result = int(numbers[0]) + operator + int(numbers[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt `operator` module and define a `mappings` dictionary that map the given operator to its corresponding operation.
Use:

```
import operator

mappings = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul, '/': operator.floordiv}

equation = "5 + 6"
n1, op, n2 = equation.split()
result = mappings[op](int(n1), int(n2))

print(result)
```

This prints:

```
11
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct it is not possible because the operator variable is a str but the number number variable is an int and you can’t do anything with these without type conversion 
But you could accomplish your idea by using an if else statement.

Answer (score -1):

try it that works, transform you equation in a string and use the eval() function

```
result = numbers[0] + operator + numbers[1]
print(eval(result))
```

Comment: eval is dangerous, and it's not needed here

Comment: there are several ways to do the same thing, he didn’t ask for one that wasn’t dangerous, so eval works :)